# Where binary in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

is there any equivalent statement in oracle for MySQL's Binary ?

Example:

```
Select * from table1 where BINARY column1 = BINARY column2;
```

It forces a exact case-sensitive match.
Is there any different statement besides to convert to UPPER or LOWER both columns ?

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow the question.  `select * from table1 where column1 = column2` will do an exact case-sensitive match.  Guessing from your answer, perhaps you want to do a case-insensitive match?

Comment: You're right, I had not tested the answer. It would be "Latin_CS"

Comment: You get an exact case-sensitive match without any `NLSSORT` in Oracle-- that's just the standard behavior (unless you have set some non-default `NLS_SORT` or `NLS_COMP` settings for your session which would be quite rare).  What problem are you solving by specifying `NLSSORT` that wouldn't be solved by simply checking whether the two columns are equal?

Comment: I'm migrating a mysql procedure with this syntax: 

`SELECT x.cod_artic FROM articulo x WHERE x.id_impto = pid_imptof AND BINARY x.cod_rubro = BINARY fn_function_name(a.cod_artic)`

  
I did not know if it was a different problem, i tried to migrate it as seemed as possible. So you say i don't need NLSSORT, the normal behavior will do the same work ??

Comment: Have you tried `select * from table1 where column1 = column2`?  Does that do what you want?  If not, why not?  What is the `NLSSORT` function doing for you that a straight comparison isn't?  If the `NLSSORT` answer is correct then you probably don't want an exact case-sensitive match and we need to correct your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE NLSSORT(column1, 'NLS_SORT = Latin_CS') = NLSSORT(column2, 'NLS_SORT = Latin_CS')
```

Found the answer somewhere.